# Spreadsheet script - Deleting Cells every sunday

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

This code is supposed to do is to delete the rows D6:D13 every week from now on. Can you tell me if it works as I intended it to do.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var OneWeekAfter = new Date();

    if(OneWeekAfter = currentDate)
    {
        sheet.deleteCell(D6);
        sheet.deleteCell(D7);
        sheet.deleteCell(D8);
        sheet.deleteCell(D9);
        sheet.deleteCell(D10);
        sheet.deleteCell(D11);
        sheet.deleteCell(D12);
        sheet.deleteCell(D13);

        oneweekafter.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Time-driven trigger. From the Script Editor menu, Select Resources.Select Current Project trigger. Click to add new trigger. Pick your function (myFunction), Time-driven,Week timer, Every Sunday, set a time. Save and the function will run every Sunday. You can simplify your code like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("D6:D13").clearContent()
}
```

Comment: If this works for you, can you please approve the answer? Thanks.